# Trying to get a simple loop of JSON passed to POST - Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, loops, parsing, post

I have a WS using Flask/python 2.7. I have 1 JSON object passed to the WS. I have been successful in capturing the object and returning the whole JSON.

I have looked all over for examples (many use print of test dataset in python) and have tried `json.dumps`, `json.loads`, `json.dump`, `json.load`, for loops, etc.

What I would like to do seems simple and I know it is me, but I get errors no matter what I try.  I am trying to parse the JSON, put the values in to variables, and do "stuff".

This works:

```
@app.route('/v1/test', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        return "JSON Message: " + json.dumps(request.json, separators=(',',':'))
    else:
         return "415 Unsupported Media Type"
```

This does not (and many variations of this using different things):

```
jsonobject = json.dumps(request.json)
pstring = json.loads(jsonobject)
for key, value in pstring.iteritems():
   return value
```

What I want to do (pseudo code):

```
for each JSON
get the name value pairs in to a place where I can do something like this (which was done on a flat file)
    input_data = pd.read_csv(sio, delimiter=',', names=columns)
    probs = model.predict_proba(input_data)
```

I am sure I didn't make this as clear as I could but it is a challenge because I get errors like below (examples -- not all at once of course) with all the different things I try:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'translate'
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

So after all that, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Here is what the JSON looks like:  
 [ {
    "val1":2098578793,
    "val2":0,
    "val3":-3 } ]

Comment: You don't need to dump or load anything; you only need to use `request.json`, which gives you a Python object.

Comment: In other words, you have a *Python list object with dictionaries in it, already*.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand.  Here is error:  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.  Here is the code I just tested:  #!/flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, json, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/v1/test', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        print 'here'
        jsonobject = request.json
        return jsonobject
    else:
        return "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: That's because you must return a string from a Flask view.